# Where to ask questions related to graphic design

Tags: support, site-recommendation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Q&A site for graphics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80041/is-there-a-qa-site-for-graphics)

Is there a Stack Exchange site, or any site similar to Stack Overflow, or an active discussion forum, for people having technical issues relating to designing graphics? The graphics could be for websites and applications, or for general use.

Comment: might want to ask this question on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80041/196107

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want [doctype.com](http://doctype.com/). From the front page:

> You can ask questions about CSS, HTML, web design and email design.

Comment: great! i was not aware of doctype! thanks..