# Is there a Q&A site for graphics?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Q&A site dedicated to graphics? I was using vfxoverflow.com but it seems dead.

I mainly want to ask questions about photoshop, fireworks, etc.

Comment: graphicdesign.stackexchange.com?

Comment: could my question http://superuser.com/questions/248251/export-layer-as-a-file-in-adobe-fireworks be moved there?

Comment: maybe moderators can do that, I'm not sure. If there's no mod action, I think it's okay to ask again on Graphic Design

Comment: Flag your question for moderator attention and request a migration to the new site.

Answer (score 3):

You might get an answer on [Super User](http://superuser.com). It's not all hardware and operating system questions on there.

Another alternative is the [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) site, but that's still in beta so you'd need to a) get a moderator to migrate the question for you and b) have a question that was a *very* good fit for the site.